# How do create this gmail app effect on Honeycomb

Tags: android-fragments, android

Attached is the screenshot of the UI that I would like to have in my app. When I click on the listitems on the fragment on the left side I see a arrow pointing(question mark in red) on the list item which was clicked, I would like to know how can we achieve this in UI layout. Any special settings to be set?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at the same feature.

To implement similar, I'd suggest showing an image on the selected item in the list, this would require code rather than Layout XML, It would be controlled by the list fragment when an item is selected.  That way you get the visual effect that the two fragments are related via the arrow image.

Did you end up giving it a go for yourself?

Comment: Even I had the same approach of showing an image which mathces with the fragment on right and has a border so that it gives aon outlook of an arrow.